# How to Remove File Name with Extension from File Path Field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an Image path Field in the table and I want to get path without filename and it's an extension.

I tried using the POSITION of the charecture  way but didn't get the accurate output.

```
LEFT("My_Path", POSITION('\' IN REVERSE("My_Path")) - 1)
```

The file path is something like

```
\Nikunj\Images\1.png
```

My expected result is

```
Nikunj\Images\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `SUBSTRING`

```
select substring (mypath from '(^.*\\)' ) ;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f2ff7f1e532ee70b1d11daa58cfb60b2)

Comment: Thank you, Kaushik Nayak, your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try following example it is working correctly.

SELECT concat(SPLIT_PART('\Nikunj\Images\1.png', '\', 2),'\',SPLIT_PART('\Nikunj\Images\1.png', '\', 3),'\') as c2;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, friends, I got a solution for that and this is my solution.

```
concat(RTRIM(REPLACE(My_Path, reverse(substring(reverse(My_Path)  from 1 for strpos(reverse(My_Path),'\')-1)),''),'\'),'\') AS VolumePath
```

This solution may help you in the feature.

Thanks for your answers friends.